# How to specify multiple media_dir in MiniDLNA

Tags: mediaserver, dlna, minidlna

I would like to specify multiple `media_dir` path as below :

**minidlna.conf**

```
media_dir=/path/to/Videos1/
media_dir=/path/to/Videos2/
media_dir=/path/to/Musics1/
media_dir=/path/to/Musics2/
```

By default it just counts last `media_dir` line.

Is there any way to do such thing?

Comment: Did you recreate your media database after changing the .conf file (`minidlna -R`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the media_dir just right. **But please delete the quotation marks**!

As the first comment suggests you need to reload your media database. I do this by having set inotify=yes in /etc/minidlna.conf

```
# Automatic discovery of new files in the media_dir directory.
inotify=yes
```

then use command

`sudo service minidlna force-reload`

in Terminal to reload the media database. Depending on the size and file number of your media_dirs you will have to wait some time until the media database is updated.

To check if everything works like it should I troubleshoot the media database, by opening it with **SQLite Manager Plugin for Firefox** and check if the desired files are to find inside of table OBJECTS. You will need basic SQL knowledge to work with the plugin.

If it doesn't work check the permissions on the files, that's a problem I often run into. Be sure the permission allows the user "minidnla" to have access.

Comment: worked like a charm.